# grunt.event.on 'watch' unable to run task

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a watch for *.css files and on the event watch I would like call the cssmin task using code.
Here is the watch

```
'stylesheet-css':
    files: ['public/stylesheets/*.css']
```

and on the code for event watch

```
grunt.event.on 'watch', (action,filepath)->
    return if filepath.has '.min'       
    grunt.task.run 'cssmin:stylesheet-css' ## this doesn't seem to do anything.
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused... why do you have that second block of code? The first block is telling grunt to run the `cssmin:stylesheet-css` task when your `*.css` files change. Why do you need the event handler? Also, I don't think it would ever work since your watch task is excluding `*.min.css` files and the event handler seems to only run if the file IS a `.min` file.

Comment: updated to remove the task

Comment: Aah... better, but still a little confused. You want to run a css minification task on files that have `.min` in the name? Are they not already minified? Would the file even exist on the first run?